# Why doesn't C++ program wait a sec for 2nd iteration like it does for 1st iteration before printing a character

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
    unsigned long long j = 0;
    while(j++ <= 10000000);
    cout<<"A";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
   return 0;
}
```

While running this code there's a small time-interval before printing first 'A', all other A's get printed instantly after that. Can someone explain to me why does this happen ?

Comment: Are you sure the initial delay isn't just the delay for the program to start? Try putting a cout statement immediately after the entry point to main() and see if there's a noticeable delay between it and the first 'A'. If you're building an optimized build I would expect the optimizer to get rid of the delay loop.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that too. cout at entry point is printed instantly, then a second delay, then 40 'A's are printed instantly

Comment: A non-useful while loop is a terrible way to try to implement a `sleep` function.  Your compiler is likely eliminating it completely.

Comment: Even if the loop isn't optimised out, a modern computer can count to 10 million in the blink of an eye.

Comment: @MikeSeymour :put an extra zero there and you can see the delay.

Comment: @ZacHowland : Can you please tell how does the compiler do that?

Comment: @ChintanGhate When it does its second pass on your code, it sees you have several items that other things do not depend on, and will realize that this is non-useful code.  Granted, this is not typically done with debug builds (optimizations turned off), but even then, counting to 10 million is done very quickly (as Mike Seymour has pointed out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output in C++ is *buffered*. This means that a bunch of characters are collected together and output at the same time, either when the buffer is full or the program ends, or when the stream is flushed (with `endl` for example).

Comment: Plus a loop of 10e6 on a modern processor will not take a human-perceptible amount of time.

Comment: You can also use `flush` to flush it without any other side effects.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yeah, flushing the buffer did the trick. Its the buffered output that was printing all characters at once. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees your j. It sees what you do to j. it sees that you never once use j. So it just skips anything doing with j all together. You want to use a sleep function

tl;dr; The compiler is outsmarting your bad code.

Comment: It's always possible to have optimizations turned off, this is the default I believe for debug builds.